# Como verificar se um Arquivo pode ser criado numa Pasta antes de tentar criá-lo nela?

Tags: java, arquivo

Meu programa permite que usuário defina uma Pasta, e posteriormente o programa irá criar um Novo Arquivo nesta Pasta.

Entretanto, o programa não é capaz de criar um Arquivo em qualquer Pasta, por exemplo:

> - Cria o Novo Arquivo na Pasta normalmente:
>     `new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\novoArquivo.txt");`

---

> - Lança uma Exception: *java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\novoArquivo.txt (Acesso negado)*:
>     `new FileOutputStream("C:\\novoArquivo.txt");`

Eu **não** estou tentando fazer o programa ter permissão para criar Arquivos em qualquer pasta, apenas preciso saber com **antecedência** (antes de tentar criar o Arquivo) se o programa será ou não capaz de criar o Arquivo na Pasta escolhida pelo usuário.

Se o usuário escolher uma Pasta na qual o programa não é capaz de criar Arquivos,  o usuário será avisado imediatante e não poderá avançar até escolher outra Pasta.

---

Eu pensei em usar um `try/catch` como `if/else` para saber se o Arquivo pode ser criado ou não, colocando dentro desse `try/catch` um `new FileOutputStream(pathDaPastaEscolhida);`, o problema é que, se Não lançar Exception, o Arquivo é imediatamente criado (sem pedir confirmação do usuário e sem dar a ele a oportunidade de escolher outra Pasta antes de efetivamente criar o Arquivo).

O Arquivo só deveria ser criado quando o usuário clicar em "Avançar", e, o botão "Avançar" deve ficar desabilitado até o programa ter certeza de que é capaz de criar o Arquivo na Pasta escolhida pelo usuário.

---

Criei um código de exemplo compilável para ajudá-los a ter ideia do que preciso:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class CriadorDeArquivo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File novoArquivo1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\novoArquivo.txt");
        criarArquivoSeForPossivel(novoArquivo1); //Cria o Arquivo como esperado

        File novoArquivo2 = new File("C:\\novoArquivo.txt");
        criarArquivoSeForPossivel(novoArquivo2); //ERRO: Lança uma Exception ao invés de mostrar a "Mensagem2"
    }

    public static void criarArquivoSeForPossivel(File novoArquivo) {
        if (isPodeSerCriado(novoArquivo)) {
            System.out.println("Com certeza é possível criar o Arquivo neste local, ele será criado..."); //Mensagem0
            criarArquivo(novoArquivo); 
            System.out.println("O Arquivo foi Criado!"); //Mensagem1
        } else {
            System.out.println("O Arquivo não pode ser criado nesse local, escolha outro local."); //Mensagem2
        }
    }

    public static void criarArquivo(File novoArquivo) {
        try {
            new FileOutputStream(novoArquivo); //Cria o Novo Arquivo na Pasta
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPodeSerCriado(File arquivo) {
        //O que colocar aqui para determinar se esse arquivo pose ser criado ou não?
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente usar o método [`isWritable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isWritable-java.nio.file.Path-) da classe `Files`:

```
public static boolean isPodeSerCriado(File arquivo) {
    return Files.isWritable(arquivo.toPath());
}
```

Vale mencionar a ressalva da [**documentação**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isWritable-java.nio.file.Path-) quanto ao uso deste método para este fim:

> Observe que o resultado desse método está imediatamente desatualizado, não há garantia de que uma tentativa subsequente de abrir o arquivo para escrita tenha êxito (ou mesmo que ele vá acessar o mesmo arquivo). Deve-se ter cuidado ao usar este método em aplicações sensíveis à segurança.

---

Fiz um teste com esse método com o código abaixo:

```
File file = new File("C:\\TESTEJAVA\\test.txt");

System.out.println(Files.isWritable(new File("C:\\TESTEJAVA").toPath()));
file.createNewFile();
```

As permissões da pasta estavam as seguintes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado foi:

> ```
> false  
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Acesso negado
>     at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
>     at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
>     at othertests.ChecarPermissaoTest.main(ChecarPermissaoTest.java:14)
> ```

Até ai o funcionamento do método está correto, sem permissão de gravar ou modificar, a exceção e o retorno `false` são esperados.

Após editar as permissões para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado foi `true` e o arquivo foi criado com sucesso.

Não sei se este método pode garantir em todos os cenários se a pasta permite ou não escrever nela, mas pelo teste acima, é possivel ver que funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Eu já havia tentado esse método, mas ele sempre retorna false porque ele verifica se o Arquivo ja existe, como descrito na documentação: `return true if and only if the file system actually contains a file denoted by this abstract pathname and the application is allowed to write to the file; false otherwise.`; ou seja, não funciona para verificar se posso **criar** um arquivo, só funciona para verificar se posso **sobrescrever** um arquivo existente.

Comment: @Douglas veja a edição, tente com ela.

Comment: `System.out.println(new File("C:\\").canWrite());` retornou `true` ao invés de retornar `false`. Ou seja, ele diz que "dá pra escrever em C:\" mas na hora de criar um arquivo em "C:\" ele lança uma Exception.

Comment: @Douglas eu editei a resposta, tente com o código editado, essa solução anterior era bastante falha mesmo.

Comment: `Files.isWritable(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\").toPath());` retornou true corretamente e `Files.isWritable(new File("C:\\").toPath());` retornou false corretamente. Parece que isso vai resolver o problema, vou fazer mais testes depois e aceito sua resposta caso confirme. Muito obrigado.

Comment: `isPodeSerCriado` - não sei se você matou a língua portuguesa ou a língua inglesa com isso. Talvez as duas. No entanto, fica com meu +1 de qualquer jeito. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu só copiei o método no código da pergunta, pensei em comentar, mas fiquei com receio de pecar por excesso de preciosismo em reparar isso.

Comment: @Articuno Foi mal, li a pergunta com muita pressa, até porque já estava respondida.